# Writing udev rule for fixed mount point for hotswap SATA devices (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, automount, udev

I have two SATA drive bays (hot-swap) and I want the first partition of the drives to be mounted to `/media/disk01/` and `/media/disk02/` ignoring all other partitions.

The automounter should be turned off for all (SATA and USB) devices.

`udevadm`gives me `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata5/host4/` and `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/` for these SATA ports on the mainboard.

I found 
https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/
and tried to use it as a starting point, but unfortunately I got stuck at the very beginning: No matter what ACTION/RUN lines I write, the drives get automounted by `usdisksd`...

Is there a tutorial howto write/debug udev rules? How can I "replace" the automounter functionality uf Ubuntu with my own rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally USB (removable) media are automatically mounted upon media insertion. If you want to suppress that, you can [configure/tweak](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USBID_MODEL_ID) yr box:

- open terminal (CTRL-ALT+T) and type in: `$ dconf-editor`
- go to `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling` and check off the `automount` option

The above should take care of the automounter being turned off by default for all removable media devices.

Turning to the udev rule, you need to:

- Check what yr devices' properties are; do in terminal: 
  `$ udevadm info -q all -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdXY)`
  where for each device X is a letter and Y a digit that correspond to each partition you want to mount on `/media/disk01/` and `/media/disk02/`.
  For each device partition note: `DEVNAME`, as well as the `ID_MODEL_ID` and `ID_VENDOR_ID`. The latter two consist of 4 alphanumerical characters each.
- Check that DEVNAME correspond to the partition you want to mount.
- In terminal, do: 
  `$ udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdXY)`
  where `/dev/sdXY` stands for each one of yr DEVNAME values.
- Look for the section where you recognize the values of `ID_MODEL_ID` and `ID_VENDOR_ID` as you noted them. It might be the "parent device" section, coming immediately after the top-most "device" section of the output
- Write yr udev rules as:

In `/etc/udev/rules.d/70_hot-swap-mount.rules`:

```
  # to create mount-points and mount devices
  KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="fill-in-model-id-here", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="fill-in-vendor-id-here", ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/disk0Z", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/disk0Z"

  # to unmount devices and remove mount-points
  KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="fill-in-model-id-here", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="fill-in-vendor-id-here", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/disk0Z", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/disk0Z"
```

In the same rule, repeat all of the above for each of the two devices you want to mount. Values of `ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}` and `ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}` will be different for each device and "Z" in `/dev/disk0Z` is either 1 or 2 as a function of the device being considered.

As per the link you provided as reference, you can indeed provide more sophisticated filesystem specific mount options by writing yr rules a little differently. Depending on the filesystem, that may include ownership, `rwx` access, etc.

For a tutorial, look at [this](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html).

HTH.